# hover: помогите пожалуйста

Tags: css3, html5

```
**HTML**

<div id="box1">
  <img url:() width:"200">
   <a href ="..."> open </a>
</div>

**CSS**
#id
{
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

a
{
font-size: 100px;
color: white;
}

:href ????
```

как мне сделать так, чтоб при указании блока #box1 у меня светился bg тега a ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что то синтаксис у Вас какой-то странный, предположу что вы хотели воспользоваться селектором дочернего элемента:

```
 #box1:hover > a {}
```

```css
#box1{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 130px;
}

a {
  color: white;
  font-size:50px;
}

#box1:hover > a {
  color: red ;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
   <a href ="..."> open </a>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, просто запутался немного, и ставил тег а перед hover )